# (Token-based A&A): send the token on every request to the server

Tags: node.js, angularjs, authentication, authorization, ejs

I am debugging a token-based A&A module in node.js + angularJS. In this approach, server authenticates the user and responds with a token. This token is saved in a local memory (client side) and user sends the token on every request to the server using the attached code.

However, I face a weird situation:

1. I login to www.test.com
2. Then I can see my dashboard: www.test.com/dashboard
3. Next, I logout from my dashboard
4. Afterwards, I open a new tab and type "www.test.com/dashboard" in the address bar of the browser. I expected the user directly go to the login page. However, for 1-2 seconds I see my dashboard (e.g., www.test.com/dashboard) and then it goes to login page !!!! I dont understand why it shows my dashboard for 1-2 seconds !!!

I guess the reason is that developers did not attached the token to GET request! any suggestion to remove the problem?
btw, where is the best location (for both angularJS and EJS) to save the token to be able to send it with all requests to server (ajax, GET, ..., websocket) ?

```
    app.factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($window, $q) {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($window.sessionStorage.getItem('token')) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');
            }
            return config || $q.when(config);
        },
        response: function(response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                // TODO: Redirect user to login page.
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
});

// Register the previously created AuthInterceptor.
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
```

Comment: put a resolve option in your route dashboard view definition so that it won't load the view until that promise successfully completes or rejects, make it resolve if status != 401 and reject otherwise

Comment: with session your method works, since browser automatically sends the session data to the server. However, for token according to my understanding developers first load the dashboard page for 1-2 seconds to send the token to the server and then server investigate the token and route the user to login page. Is there any way to automatically send the token with GET (similar to session)?

Comment: Without session it also works, it's just that you should check if you have already a token in localstorage through resolve, that should be the correct way to delay view loading and if not authentified reject the promise and handle the onRouteChangeError event to redirect to login page